# How to search in multiple columns using one like operator in HQL (hibernate sql)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Hope someone can help me with this HQL query.

I'm using:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
```

where the sql is:

```
select distinct c.id from EstateConsumer as c where c.clientId = ? and  (c.vehicleReg1 or c.vehicleReg2) like ?
```

but is getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: or near line 1, column 121
```

So how can you use the "OR" syntax by using one "like"?

The following however works:

```
select distinct c.id from EstateConsumer as c where c.clientId = ? and  c.vehicleReg1 like ? or c.vehicleReg2 like ?
```

but I don't want to use multiple "like"'s

Comment: Why not the version that works? I think it solves the problem except for missing braces.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?  this depend on your dbms

Comment: @mm759, because of the way the program is coded and structured... it passes only 2 parameters (one for clientId and one for the multiple vehicleReg columns).

Comment: @YCF_L, i'm using HQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with **REGEX** so for example :

```
REGEXP_LIKE('Hello world', 'Hello', 'mars') = 1
```

So you can replace your query :

```
select ... where c.clientId = ? and  c.vehicleReg1 like ? or c.vehicleReg2 like ?
```

by using this query here :

```
SELECT ... WHERE c.clientId = ? and REGEXP_LIKE(?, c.vehicleReg1, c.vehicleReg2) = 1
-- -------------------------------------^^
```

This mean if your value `?` is like `c.vehicleReg1` or `c.vehicleReg2` return `1` else the matching is wrong

---

**Note**

> @mm759, because of the way the program is coded and structured... it
>   passes only 2 parameters (one for clientId and one for the multiple
>   vehicleReg columns)

You can use the same parameter in multiple positions in your query like this :

```
q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(
"select ... where c.clientId = :par1 and  c.vehicleReg1 like :par2 or c.vehicleReg2 like :par2");
//-------------------------------^^----------------------------^^--------------------------^^

q.setParamettre("par1", "value1");
q.setParamettre("par2", "value2");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion! That regex worked and got past the createQuery exception I had. Quick question, is the REGEXP_LIKE replacing the param with % sign before and after the text? I'm asking this because i'm already passing the % sign in my "?" parameter.

Comment: @user2319262 yes it replace the % in the start and in the end, here is a link you can understand more how you can use REGEX_LIKE http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11741.html, `select target
from   targets
where  target LIKE '%bc%' ;` can replaced by `select target
from   targets
where  REGEXP_LIKE( target, 'bc' ) ;` hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

A complicated variant such as the regexp_like variant proposed by @YCF_L likely includes additional performance overhead, if only because the DBMS has trouble optimizing such a query to the same degree as one using 'familiar' operators.

I would go for a solution where you reuse a parameter.

You state,

> because of the way the program is coded and structured... it passes only 2 parameters (one for clientId and one for the multiple vehicleReg columns)

I don't understand why you can't just capture one of the parameters and reuse it. YCL_F gives a very nice example of one in his update, but as long as you're using JPA, why not go for the full JPA solution? This has added benefits in that it is typesafe, refactorsafe and can be (better) cached than a native SQL query.

For example,

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<C> jpaquery = cb.createQuery(C.class);
Root<C> root = jpaquery.from(C.class);

jpaquery.where(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(C_.clientId), parameter1),cb.or(cb.like(root.get(C_.vehicleReg1), parameter2), cb.like(root.get(C_.vehicleReg2), parameter2)));
jpaQuery.select(...);

return getEntityManager().createQuery(jpaQuery).getResultList();
```